# React Native ListView cells are overlapping

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

My `ListView` cells are overlapping to each other as illustrated in the screenshot. It was working fine when I was using `react-native` version 0.23 but after upgrading to 0.30 the UI is destructing in `5c & 5s` devices not in simulator. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: try setting LayoutParams

Comment: What do you meant by that? I have added the necessary `flexbox` params. Can you please elaborate? As far I know you are saying about Android RelativeLayout parameters. I am working on iOS react-native

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also had the same problem when I put data before current data. I managed to workaround the problem by emptying the state first, then fill it after.

BEFORE:

```
this.setState({
    news: news.concat(this.state.news),
    storiesDataSource: this.state.storiesDataSource.cloneWithRows(news.concat(this.state.news)),
});
```

AFTER:

```
this.setState({
    storiesDataSource: this.state.storiesDataSource.cloneWithRows([])
}, function() {
    this.setState({
        news: news.concat(this.state.news),
        storiesDataSource: this.state.storiesDataSource.cloneWithRows(
            news.concat(this.state.news)
        ),
    });
}.bind(this))
```